# how to insert data from table 1 field to table 2 field

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
            strSQL = "INSERT INTO MEMBER (" & _
                        "MERCHANT_UID, MEMBER_ID, ACCOUNT_ID, LOGIN_PWD, SALUTATION, FULL_NAME, " & _
                        "IC_NO, DOB, GENDER, NATIONALITY, CITY, STATE, " & _
                        "COUNTRY, POSTCODE, PHONE_MOBILE, PHONE_HOUSE, PHONE_OFFICE, EMAIL, SOURCE, IS_REQ_CHG_PWD, " & _
                        "ADDRESS_1, ADDRESS_2, ADDRESS_3, " & _
                        "CREATED_BY, CREATED_DATETIME, " & _
                        "MODIFIED_BY, MODIFIED_DATETIME) " & _
                     "VALUES (" & _
                        "@MERCHANT_UID, @MEMBER_ID, @ACCOUNT_ID, @LOGIN_PWD, @SALUTATION, @FULL_NAME, " & _
                        "@IC_NO, @DOB, @GENDER, @NATIONALITY, @CITY, @STATE, " & _
                        "@COUNTRY, @POSTCODE, @PHONE_MOBILE, @PHONE_HOUSE, @PHONE_OFFICE, @EMAIL, @SOURCE, @IS_REQ_CHG_PWD, " & _
                        "@ADDRESS_1, @ADDRESS_2, @ADDRESS_3, " & _
                        "@CREATED_BY, @CREATED_DATETIME, " & _
                        "@MODIFIED_BY, @MODIFIED_DATETIME);"
```

above is table 1 which is member table. table 2 will be Account_ID_Format (field name) from member_activation table

- i want to insert account_ID_Format from the above query into table 2. how can i do that?

Comment: By using an insert ... select ... statement

Comment: do you want to insert new row or want to update row ?

Comment: Perhaps a trigger?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the insert select statement in that way

```
INSERT INTO tablename (columnname1,columnname2,..) SELECT columnname1,columnname2,.. FROM tablename2 WHERE id = 4
```

this will do the job

```
INSERT INTO members (account_ID_Format) SELECT account_ID_Format FROM members_activation WHERE id = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO member_activation
SELECT account_ID_Format
FROM member
WHERE <condition>
```

OR

```
Select account_ID_Format
into
member_activation
from member
where <condition>
```

Comment: is it possible if i insert into both the table

Comment: Make use of Trigger if you want to insert in 2nd table when insert happens in 1st Table.